# Get execution time of an HTTP request in Angular

Tags: angular, http

How can I get the execution time of an HTTP request in Angular (I'm using version 5)?

This code returns an incorrect value due to asynchronicity:

```
  myFunction(someVariable):void {

     let startFrom = new Date().getTime();         

     this.http.post(myurl, myjson).subscribe(res => 
     console.log(res),
     console.log(new Date().getTime() - startFrom));

  }
```

Comment: The problem there is that you’re passing the result of the logging as the second callback to subscribe, so that it happens before the request gets made, as much as asynchronicity. But in general you can get access to the progress events per the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: Why do you log the time in the error callback? And why don't you define startFrom anywhere?

Comment: I forgot to include it. It was in the original code. I've just edited the code.

Comment: Why do you think that this code prints an incorrect value? What do you expect, why, and what happens instead?

Comment: For example, I get between 8-12 ms with this approach while the console displays something like 300 ms for the execution time of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the current time minus the current time (i.e. 0) as the error callback, instead of computing the duration when the operation succeeds. The code should be

```
  myFunction(someVariable):void {

     let startFrom = new Date().getTime();         

     this.http.post(myurl, myjson).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res),
       console.log(new Date().getTime() - startFrom));
     });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using rxjs operators, it add the advantage to be easily included in a `pipe` chain

```
 myFunction(someVariable):void {
     this.http.post(myurl, myjson).pipe(timeInterval()).subscribe(res => {
       console.log('Res', res.value),
       console.log('Time', res.interval);
     });

  }
```